# HTTP Load Balancing - You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port

Tags: google-compute-engine

We are trying to test using the HTTP Load Balancing instead of the Network Load Balancing. When we try and go to http://beta.stubwire.com/ we get a 400 error saying we are speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port but then if I go to https://beta.stubwire.com it works fine. I have included some screen shots of the load balancer below, is the error in here or is it the way the server is configured?

[image: http load balancing 1]
[image: http load balancing 2]

[image]

Comment: As of right now, sometimes the page loads and sometimes I get the Bad Request as it is mentioned above. It is loading a instance group so all servers should be configured the exact same way and this happens on .php pages or .html pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally able to figure this out. Under the "Backend services" of the load balancer you can click on Edit. Then you can select the different "Backend" that you wanted it to contain. On this we had specified "80, 443" as it mentioned we could list both. But we had a backend service created for secure and non secure pages. So only specifying the port that that service uses fixed that issue.

[image]